# New to python and need to know how __init__ behave

Tags: python

I want to know why the output does not change my namef to "yolo" , and why it returns none x2 when I remove the # from the first print statement

```
class Class():
    def __init__(self, namef, namel):
        self.name1 = namef
        self.name2 = namel
        self.email = print(f"{self.name1}{self.name2}@google.com")


    def introself(self):
        return(f"Hello guys my name is {self.name1}{self.name2} and I am a human")

human1 = Class("chandra", "Shekar")

# print(human1.email)

human1.name1="yolo"

print(human1.email)
```

Comment: `self.email=print(f"{self.name1}{self.name2}@google.com")` -->  `self.email=f"{self.name1}{self.name2}@google.com"` - remove the print

Comment: If you'd fix that `print` thing, you'd set `email` to a string. That string won't update implicitly if you change some variable that was used to create it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By setting `human1.name1="yolo"` you have updated an attribute of the instance "human1" of the class "Class". Now if you print human1.name1 it'll be "yolo" as expected. namef is a parameter, not a variable, not a value, so I don't see how you could even see that it isn't changed as it never existed. As for human1.email, you've set it as print("a string"), print is a built-in function, calling print like this prints the string, but returns none, and then you printed none, so it shows none.

**Edit** 
`namef` is a parameter, `name1` is an attribute of the class. `__init__` is a function that is called every time an instance of a class is created, which initializes all the attributes that you passed in as parameter when you created the instance. Say we call your class `Human` instead of "Class", in your example, when you did `human1 = Human("chandra", "Shekar")`, this is the equivalent of `human1 = Human(namef="chandra", namel="Shekar")`. Now the `__init__` function of the `Human` class is called, setting `human1.name1` to `namef` as you demanded, which is "chandra", and same goes for `name2`, which is set to `namel`, which is "Shekar". The parameters `namef` and `namel`, when passed into the function, are stored very temporarily in stack (I think) but you can only access them within the function itself. So within the `__init__` function, you can use `namef` and `namel` however you want. For example:

```
class Human:
    def __init__(self, namef, namel):
        print(namef + " " + namel)

human1 = Human("chandra", "Shekar")
```

Would print out "chandra Shekar". but trying to do `human1.namef` just doesn't make sense.

You've created an instance of "Human" called "human1", which now has the attributes name1 and name2. These two values can then be accessed through `human1.name1` and `human1.name2`.

Comment: so you mean namef(parameter) and name1(parameter) are empty boxes with no item(value) in them? even if so i still dont get it completely

Comment: @VIKING Edited with some detail

Answer (score 0):

```
class Class():
    def __init__(self, namef, namel):
        self.name1 = namef
        self.name2 = namel
        # self.email now points to the print FUNCTION with this argument
        self.email = print(f"{self.name1}{self.name2}@google.com")

    def introself(self):
        return f"Hello guys my name is {self.name1}{self.name2} and I am a human"

human1 = Class("chandra", "Shekar")

# This essentially calls print(print(f"{self.name1}{self.name2}@google.com"))
# which returns None since the inner print call returns None
print(human1.email)

human1.name1="yolo"

# email is only defined in the init function, and depends on namef and namel
# email wont have the updated name1
print(human1.email)
```

A fix: using setters to change email when you set namef and namel

```
class Class():
    def __init__(self, namef, namel):
        self._namef = namef
        self._namel = namel
        self.email = f"{self._namef}{self._namel}@google.com"

    @property
    def namef(self):
        return self._namef

    @property 
    def namel(self):
        return self._namel

    @namef.setter 
    def namef(self, value):
        self._namef = value 
        self.email = f"{self._namef}{self._namel}@google.com"

    @namel.setter 
    def namel(self, value):
        self._namel = value 
        self.email = f"{self._namef}{self._namel}@google.com"

    def introself(self):
        return f"Hello guys my name is {self.namef}{self.namel} and I am a human"

human1 = Class("chandra", "Shekar")

print(human1.email) # chandraShekar@google.com

human1.namef = "yolo"

print(human1.email) # yoloShekar@google.com

human1.namel = "fomo"

print(human1.email) # yolofomo@google.com
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Class():
    def __init__(self,namef,namel):
        self.name1=namef
        self.name2=namel
        
        
    def email(self):
        return f"{self.name1}{self.name2}@google.com"


    def introself(self):
        return(f"Hello guys my name is {self.name1} {self.name2} and i am a human")

human1=Class("chandra", "Shekar")

 # print (human1.email)

human1.name1="yolo"

print (human1.email())
print(human1.introself())
```